# Pointwise Limits of functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

So the definition of a pointwise limit of a sequence of functions $f_{n}$ is

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n} = f$ if  and only if $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}(x) = f(x) \forall x$ in the domain.

Could anyone please explain what this means intuitively, I am having a hard time picturing this in my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $\;x\in $ the domain, we get a *sequence* $\;\left\{f_n(x)\right\}\;$ of numbers, and thus we can talk of this sequence's limit when $\;n\to\infty\;$ . If this limit exists finitely for all $\;x\in $ the domain, say to a number $\;f(x)\;$ , then we say the functions sequence $\;\{f_n\}\;$ converges (pointwise) to the function $\;f(x)\;$.

Thus, you can see that for every point in the domain the above is just like dealing with sequences of numbers.